# SELECT with CASE after UPDATE uses old value

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I have a problem with a combination of sql statements generated by entity-framework.

It looks like the updated value of the powerloss field is not immediately set after the update statement completes and the select gets executed.

I don't know if that's even possible.
Maybe I'm just missing something.

The updated and selected rows and the data in the table after the code executes are correct.

### What it should do (and it does it 99% of the time)

I get a counterValue from a device and insert it into a table on a sql-server 2008 R2 (SP3). If the device has lost power and at some point is back, the field "powerloss" in the last counterValue entry in the database will be updated to 1(true). By default, the field is 0(false).

After that, I query the last counterValue of this device and negate it.
But only if the field "powerloss" is 0(false). Otherwise the query must return zero.

### What goes wrong

Sometimes (very rare) I get the negated counterValue when the powerloss field was updated to 1(true) right before the select...

That's at least what my log-file shows me (every query is logged).

**What the code does**

1. Create dbContext
2. BeginTransaction(isolationLevel.ReadComitted)
3. WriteNewCounterValue (after Powerloss)

   1. Update field `powerloss=true`
   2. Select counterValue depend on value in powerloss field

      ```
      offset = (From qItem In DB.SlaveCounterEntries 
                Where qItem.deviceId= deviceId
                And qItem.Received < timestamp 
                Order By qItem.Received Descending 
                Select If(qItem.Powerloss = True, 0, -qItem.CounterValue) 
                Take 1).SingleOrDefault()
      ```
   3. Insert new counterValue in Table
4. Commit Transaction
5. Dispose dbContext

**The gernerated sql statements**

The update statement:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[slaveCounter]
    SET [powerloss] = @0
    WHERE ([id] = @1)
    -- @0: 'True' (Type = Boolean)
    -- @1: '3371747' (Type = Int32)
    -- Executing at 29.06.2018 05:57:24 +02:00
    -- Completed in 0 ms with result: 1
```

The select statement (14 ms after the update):

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        CASE WHEN (1 = [Extent1].[powerloss]) THEN 0 ELSE  -([Extent1].[counterValue]) END AS [C1], 
        [Extent1].[datReceived] AS [datReceived]
        FROM [dbo].[slaveCounter] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[slaveId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[datReceived] < @p__linq__1)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[datReceived] DESC

    -- p__linq__0: '48' (Type = Int16, IsNullable = false)
    -- p__linq__1: '28.06.2018 23:00:03' (Type = DateTime2, IsNullable = false)
    -- Executing at 29.06.2018 05:57:24 +02:00
    -- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

Comment: if it's 14ms after the update, probably it is not yet committed.

Comment: how would he read the uncommitted data if he is not using NOLOCK though?  The update is in a transaction.  Could he also save a Timestamp, then log that too?

Comment: the transactions only ensure the data is read as if it was being done sequentially, the actual sequence is not ensured.

Comment: There just isn't enough information here to be able to fully understand what is going on.

Comment: Is `qItem.Received` guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: What sets the qItem.Received? Is this controlled by the database or the server(s)? Do other applications/services update these records? Does this operate on a single server or multiple instances? If the datetime value is set by an application server and there is more than one instance then differences in server date/times could cause anomalies. I'm also somewhat curious why you'd want to read data state right after performing an update? Normally I'd expect to see retrieving an entity graph, inspect, update, commit, and use the already loaded entities.

Comment: Can you post further details about the code and its implementation ?
It looks like the db context you are using is not working within the same transaction, you need either to re-design it in order to perform the update in between 
Commit Transaction and Dispose dbContextor 
or to force a IsolationLevel.ReadUnComitted, very risky in certain context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason why it *seems* that the update statement does not work:

An other transaction added a second record which had the same counterValue and was not updated and later be deleted.
So only the "correct" entry remains.

In retrospect, everything seems so clear ^^